# Refile sinatra endpoint not found on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, refile

Using Refile. Ubuntu 14.04 servers (production and development):

- uploading to S3 backend in presigned mode.
- Utilizing refile.js for upload.progress reporting

All works fine at localhost (development) but accessing the sinatra endpoint in production mode is throwing a 404, for example:

- http://mydomain/attachments/cache/presign

Uploads will ultimately complete to S3, but accessing the sinatra endpoint results in a 404. Running `rake routes` on production shows the route is registered.

Comment: where s the production server placed?

Comment: you should investigate where the 404 is risen from.... it may not be because of invalid route.